# runge kutta 2 in python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, python, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve an equation in fluid mechanics using the runge-kutta 2 method, usually it seems quite doable but in this case its with x y and z and i cant seem to make the code. Here is what i have done so far: It does return a plot but I cannot say whether it is at all meaningfull

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Define function to compute velocity field

A = 0.2
B = 1.0
C = 0.20


def velfun(x,y,z,t):
    
    xvelocity =  (A*np.sin(z) +  C*np.cos(x))
    yvelocity =  (B*np.sin(x) + A*np.cos(z))
    zvelocity =  (C*np.sin(y) + B*np.cos(x))
    return xvelocity, yvelocity, zvelocity


# Set stopping time
# and the step length
    
Nstep = 10000   
h     = 0.01

# Create arrays to store x and t values

x     = np.zeros(Nstep);
y     = np.zeros(Nstep);
z     = np.zeros(Nstep);

# Set the initial condition

x[0] = 1,
y[0] = 0,
z[0] = 0

# Carry out steps in a loop

for k in range(1,Nstep):
    
    # Provisional Euler step
    
    tt    = t[k-1]
    xx    = x[k-1]
    yy    = y[k-1]
    zz    = z[k-1]
    ux,uy,uz = velfun(xx,yy,zz,tt)
    xp    = x[k-1] + h*ux
    yp    = y[k-1] + h*uy
    zp    = z[k-1] + h*uz
    # Compute velocity at provisional point
    
    uxp,uyp,uzp = velfun(xp,yp,zp,tt+h)

    # Compute average velocity
    
    uxa = 0.5*(ux + uxp)
    uya = 0.5*(uy + uyp)
    uza = 0.5*(uz + uzp)
    
    # Make final Euler step
    # using average velocity
    
    x[k] = x[k-1] + h*uxa
    y[k] = y[k-1] + h*uya
    z[k] = z[k-1] + h*uza
    


    
# Exact solution
    


# Plot results
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(x,y,z,'b',label='x (with RK2)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, what makes you think that you're having a problem with the mathematics here? It seems to me that the issue is probably more of a programming one, so perhaps you should be posting this on some other SE site? This said, and without understanding your code, I wonder why there are no `cos(y)` in your `velfun()` function.

Comment: Appolagies I have not asked a question on here before and so was not entirely clear on how it worked. Do you mean changing the tags orr? Thanks anyway

Comment: What I meant is that Math.SE is not about programming. There are other resources like [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) in the same network. This said, thanks for fixing the presentation of the question. And again, your `velfun()` function looks quite suspicious to me. Besides the already mentioned absence of `cos(y)` (which suggests a botched copy/paste), I'm also worried about the parameter `t` being used, well, nowhere.

Comment: t is used in everything as the equations at the top are dy/dt dx/dt dz/dt. As for the cos(y) it is supposed to be that way in terms of how the problem states it.

Comment: why is there a `t` in the list of formal parameters of `velfun()` if that parameter is never used in the body of the function?

Comment: yes this is true, i have removed the t's and the function still does what it did before. I suppose the question remains for me as to whether the result the code outputs is correct

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with numerical methods, so I'll quit annoying you with code-related things. However, I'd suggest you add the `numerical-methods` tag to the question, so as to broaden its reach as much as possible. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you want to implement the [Arnold-Beltrami-Childress ABC dynamic](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29823/poincare-map-for-arnold-beltrami-childress). Note that the ABC and xyz triples are moved cyclically through each position. This is violated in your code in the last position where you have xzx instead of yzx.

Apart from some small errors or over-corrections (No commas as command separator, as that constructs lists. If the array `t` is used it must be defined before.) the other parts of your code are correct. Applying all the mentioned points gives a realistic result, extending the time span will make it visibly chaotic.

| stereopair of the corrected solution |
| --- |
| [image: stereopair] |